# How to run celery and redis in Django application

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a problem with a django application that executes stored procedures (oracle database) through celery tasks and redis. The application was running in a linux server but this fall down and then i lift the aplication up using python manage.py runserver but i don't know how to deal with the part that celery uses to run the tasks that call the stored procedures.

here a view

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def DynamicView(request):
   idc = request.GET.get('idc')
   idpl = request.GET.get('idpl')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      usuario = request.user
      rpost = request.POST
      form = DynamicForm(idpl,idc, request.POST)
      idc= request.POST.get('idcontrol')
      idpl= request.POST.get('idpl')
      if form.is_valid():
        pl_ejecutar = BuildPl(idpl,idc,usuario,rpost)
        mensaje = pl_ejecutar
        dynamicExec.delay(pl_ejecutar,idc,idpl)

      nom_control = BuscarControl(idc)
      nom_pl = BuscarControlPl(idpl)
      usu = User.objects.get(username=usuario)
      nombre_usu = usu.username 
      accion = 'Se ha ejecutado el Pl: ' \
                  + nom_pl + '. Para el Control: ' \
                  + nom_control + '. Por: ' + nombre_usu

      RegistroAcciones(usuario,accion)  

      return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
```

here a task

```
@task(queue='ds')
def dynamicExec(pl,pidc,pidpl):
    runpl = EjecutarPl()
    spe = runpl.ejecuta(pl,pidc,pidpl)
    return none
```

here the model that call de store procedure

```
class EjecutarPl():
   def ejecuta(self, plv,idcv,idplv):
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      query = "begin cbs_django.ejecutar_pl_v2(:ppl,:pidc,:pidpl); end; "
      param = {"ppl":plv,"pidc":idcv,"pidpl":idplv}
      spexec = cursor.execute(query,param)
      cursor.close()
      return spexec
```

I don't have experience using celery and redis so if anyone can help me would be thankful.

Comment: Wait, are you using `python manage.py runserver` in production?

Comment: It's also not clear what you're asking. What exactly are you having trouble with? What do you mean by "the part that celery uses to run the tasks that call the stored procedures"?

Comment: hi thanks for answer me what i want to say is that the app uses celery and redis to run task in background and the task calls some stored procedures from the database. The app run in a linux server so when the server fell dawn I restaured the aplication and until that point there hasn't  no problem but when i tryed to execute some reports in the app nothing happens and then i found that i had to run celery or redis and that part confuse me.

Comment: these are some task
@task(queue='ds')
def Matar_Task(vsid,vserial):
    killdb = Matar_Sesion()
    spk = killdb.mata(vsid,vserial)
    return None

@task(queue='ds')
def Correr_Task(vsid,vserial):
    rundb = Correr()
    spr = rundb.plsql(vsid,vserial)
    return None

Comment: i'm trying to do this celery multi start -A xmlcbs ds -c:ds 3 and then  ./manage.py celeryd but does't work

Comment: i understand that i have to start the workers and then run celery. so when the application call the task celery get the peticion but nothing happen in the console

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into [`supervisor`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps). It will allow you to run multiple scripts in different processes/daemons.